# test the timeOut in iPhone (- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request)

Tags: iphone

I would like to test the timeOut error in the requestFailed, i have do like this :

```
if ([[self.request error] code]== ASIRequestTimedOutErrorType){
    // ... 
}
```

i would like to test this  in the simulator but i don't no how to do it.

thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the URL you are addressing to non-responsive one, like http://10.0.0.1/ or similar

Answer (score 0):

Change the URL to hit this PHP script:

```
<?php    
sleep(100);
echo "You never timed out!";
?>
```